# Emails disappearing from account after moving to folder

Tags: mail.app, email, office-365

I am experiencing an odd issue when moving emails to folders. I am using Mail.app with an Office 365 account (IMAP).

Here is the sequence of steps that produces the issue for me:

- Move email to a folder
- Press Ctrl-Z to undo the move (returning it to the first folder)
- Move email to a different folder

After doing these steps, the email disappears completely. If I search for it, no results appear. If I log into the Office 365 web client, the email doesn't even show up there.

Am I doing something incorrectly?